# Vue 3 - refs inside v-for not working when onMounted event happens

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have following code for Vue (**script setup**):

```js
const { freeTables, usedTables } = storeToRefs(useTableStore())
    
let mineButton = ref()
    
const itemRefs = ref([])
    
onMounted(() => {
  mineButton = document.getElementById('mine-tables')
    
  const urlPath = window.location.pathname.slice(1).split('/')
    
  if (urlPath[0] === 'tables' && Number.isInteger(+urlPath[1])) {
    let currentTable = document.getElementById(`table-${urlPath[1]}`)
    
    // console.log(currentTable);
  }
})
```

And on template part I have this code:

```html
<tr
  @mouseenter="removeClass"
  v-for="table in usedTables"
  ref="itemRefs"
  :key="table.id"
  role="button"
  :id="`table-${table.id}`"
>
  <td
    v-tooltip="$t('tables.tooltip.show')"
    class="h5"
    @click="tableOrder(table)"
  >
    {{ table.name }}
  </td>

  <td class="col-1 text-end h3">
    <span class="badge bg-dark">
      4 <i class="fa-solid fa-chair"></i>
    </span>
  </td>

  <td
    @click="takeTable(table.id)"
    v-tooltip="$t('tables.tooltip.take')"
    v-if="+table.userID !== +userData.id && +table.waiterID !== +userData.id"
  >
    <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-solid fa-people-robbery"></font-awesome-icon>
  </td>
</tr>
```

The issue is the following: once the `onMounted` event is fired, the `itemRefs` is empty (without any elements inside). But if the hot reload is performed the `itemRefs` have proper elements. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: When I look into your code, it seems like you try to work around the reactive nature of the Vue framework. Whenever I see someone using `querySelector` It is obvious, that you should build your component differently. If you build it in a way that is intended from vue, you barely need to use `querySelector` except you integrate some plugins. The reason is mostly, that you mix data and presentation logic which you should separate.

Comment: I guess, from what I see in your code, you should have a look into the vue documentation to understand how refs work for instance how you set the `mineButton` inside `onMounted`, that is not how you should to it. So `mineButton` should be a `const` and updated like `mineButton.value = document.getElementById('mine-tables')`